# Getting issue while using ui-router of Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am getting some issue while using Angular.js Ui-router.First let me to explain my code below.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li ui-sref-active="active" ><a ui-sref=".profile">College Profile</a></li>
<li ui-sref-active="active" ><a ui-sref=".stream">College stream</a></li>
<li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref=".dept" >College Department</a></li>
<li class="dropdown " ui-sref-active="active">
<a ui-sref=".res.userrole" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Resource Management <span class="caret"></span></a>

  </li>
   <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref=".usermanagement">User Management</a></li>
  <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref=".role">User Role</a></li>
</ul>
```

When user is clicking on `Resource Management` menu the below page is opening.

```
<div class="container">
<tabset>
    <tab ui-sref="dashboard.res.userrole" ui-sref-active="active">
      <tab-heading>Add User Role</tab-heading>
    </tab>
    <tab ui-sref="dashboard.res.course" ui-sref-active="active">
      <tab-heading>Add Course</tab-heading>
    </tab>
  </tabset>
  <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

Here i need if user will select `Add course` tab the main menu `Resource Management` will be hignlight/active.In this case only it is active when user is clicking `Add User Role` tab.Please check my below route file.

```
.state('dashboard.res', {
        url: '/res',
        templateUrl: 'dashboardview/res.html',
        controller: 'resController'
    })
    .state('dashboard.res.userrole', {
        url: '/userrole',
        templateUrl: 'dashboardview/userrole.html',
        controller: 'resourceuserroleController'
    })
    .state('dashboard.res.course', {
        url: '/course',
        templateUrl: 'dashboardview/course.html',
        controller: 'resourcecourseController'
    })
```

Here i have also another issue.Suppose user is refreshing the page staying on any tab select the ,the both tab are getting highlighted.Actually here i need if Add user role`tab will select the parent menu will be highlight and same for`Add course`.I was following [this plunkr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/swUNUcvBE1DaITgWSWtD?p=preview) but in my case its not working as per required.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: It's very difficult to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @strom :Ok,let me to explain again.Here my issue is when i am clicking on  any other the child submenu rather than `Add User Role`  its parent menu `Resource Management` can not get active class and second one is if i am reloading the page staying in any child menu page,all child menu('i.e-Add User Role,Add course etc..') are getting active class means highlighting.I need here if user will click on any child menu the parent menu will also get active class with it.

Comment: @strom : Do you have any idea how to resolve this ?

Comment: Well, for issue no. 1 I have a suspicion. Angular uses different scopes for different html-elements.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i resolve this ?

Comment: Sorry, I had to go somewhere else. So, the problem could be that the `<div>` you're using for the resource mgmt. menu is an element of it's own. In other words, I suspect it's not a child node of the DOM element that contains your original form. As a result the menu itself is not in the scope of the `FormController`. Unfortunately, I don't know how to resolve this problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94094/discussion-between-subhra-and-strom).